# Big Query scheduled query saved to individual tables named with yesterdays date

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to run a scheduled query daily on big query based on the daily google analytics export. I managed to set up a query that runs but I can't get the table namning to work as I want. I want to write to an output table with naming tablename_YYYYMMDD where the date should be yesterdays date (relative to runtime). I've set up the query and the destination table name to tablename_${run_time-25h|"%Y%m%d"} with partition field left blank. Instead of producing a new table every day with the naming I intended, the scheduled query saves the result into the same table with the name tablename_ which contains a pseudo column called _PARTITIONTIME which corresponds to yesterdays date.

How can I get the scheduled query to save the result into a new table every day and not create any pseudocolumns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't need the $ as that makes it a "Ingestion-time partitioned table" so try

```
tablename_{run_time-25h|"%Y%m%d"}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need like this, no $ sign. See more format [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).

```
mytable_-25h{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}
```

runtime input: `2018-02-15 00:00:00 UTC` produces `mytable_20180214`

Comment: That also gives me an error:
Error in starting transfer runs: Request contains an invalid argument.

Comment: @Ichta That is wrong syntax as you can check in the link you provided yourself, Bobbylanks answer is OK.